# (django) strftime format does not work properly, different timezone, order

Tags: python, django, timezone, format, strftime

This is about comments of a bulletin. When someone writes a comment and push 'submit', ajax send data to pushComment() of views.py, save the data, and return to the ajax. So user can see the comment without refreshing the page.

The Problem is, the data format.

I used strftime(format) but it works with some problems.

1. TIMEZONE is not applied with new comments. my server TIMEZONE is 'asia/seoul' but new comments shows TIMEZONE as UTC. (only for new comments)
2. Format order is changed. my format is 'date to time' but time comes sonner than date.

here's my code.

views.py

```
def pushComment(request):

pk = request.POST.get('writing_id', 1)


ac = ArticleComments(
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username),
    article = FreeBoards.objects.get(id=pk),
    comments = request.POST.get('comments', 'Nothing'),
    # target = 0,
    pub_date = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0),
    like = 0,
    )
ac.save()


com_cnt = ArticleComments.objects.filter(article=pk).count()
FreeBoards.objects.filter(id=pk).update(comments = com_cnt)
user = MyUser.objects.get(nickname=request.user.myuser)
data = {
    'writing_id': pk,
    'user': user.nickname,
    'comments': ac.comments,
    # 'target': ac.target,
    'pub_date': str(ac.pub_date.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')), # why TIMEZONE is UTC ?????
    'like': ac.like,
    'com_cnt': com_cnt,
}

return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

template

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline" id="form-com-id" name="commentform" onsubmit="return false;" action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id-comment" name="comname" placeholder="Leave your comment.">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-comment-submit" OnClick="javascript:commentCheck();">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<br><br>
<div class="comments-group">
    <div id="com-start" class="panel-heading">자유로운 댓글</div>
    {% if comment_list %}
        {% for c in comment_list %}
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="{% cycle 'box1' 'box2' 'box3' 'box4' 'box5' %}">
            <div class="boxbox">
                <div class="com-user">
                    <p>작성자: {{c.user.myuser}}
                    <button onclick=deleteCom()>&times;</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="com-content ellipsis">
                    <p>{{c.comments}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="com-date"
                    <p>{{c.pub_date}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

javascript

```
$('#form-com-id').submit(function() {
  var com = $('#id-comment').val();
  if(com){
    $.ajax({
      url : "/sle/freeboards/pushComment/",
      type : "POST",
      data : {
        writing_id : '{{writing_id}}',
        comments : com,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
      },
      dataType : "json",
      success:function(data){
        $('#id-comment').val('');

        /* create elements and class matching */
        var divcomgrp = document.getElementsByClassName('comments-group');
        var divgrid = document.createElement("div");
        divgrid.className = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4';

        var divbox = document.createElement('div');
        if(data.com_cnt % 5 == 0) {
          divbox.className = 'box5';  
        } else if (data.com_cnt % 5 == 1) {
          divbox.className = 'box1';
        } else if (data.com_cnt % 5 == 2) {
          divbox.className = 'box2';
        } else if (data.com_cnt % 5 == 3) {
          divbox.className = 'box3';
        } else if (data.com_cnt % 5 == 4) {
          divbox.className = 'box4';
        }
        // quotient = data.com_cnt / 5;

        var divcontainer = document.createElement("div");
        divcontainer.className = 'boxbox';
        var divuser = document.createElement("div");
        divuser.className = 'com-user';
        var divcont = document.createElement("div");
        divcont.className = 'com-content';
        var divdate = document.createElement("div");
        divdate.className = 'com-date';

        /* create paragraphs */
        var puser = document.createElement('p');
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(data.user);
        puser.appendChild(textnode);
        var butdel = document.createElement('button');
        butdel.innerHTML = '&times';
        butdel.onclick = deleteCom;
        puser.appendChild(butdel);

        var pcomments = document.createElement('p');
        var textnode2 = document.createTextNode(data.comments);
        pcomments.appendChild(textnode2);

        var pdate = document.createElement('p');
        var textnode3 = document.createTextNode(data.pub_date);
        pdate.appendChild(textnode3);

        /* appending children */
        divuser.appendChild(puser);
        divcont.appendChild(pcomments);
        divdate.appendChild(pdate);

        divcontainer.appendChild(divuser);
        divcontainer.appendChild(divcont);
        divcontainer.appendChild(divdate);

        divbox.appendChild(divcontainer);
        divgrid.appendChild(divbox);
        divcomgrp[0].appendChild(divgrid);
      },
      failure: function(data){
        alert('fail!!');
      },
    });
  }
});
```

settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'
```

result

I cannot upload images... so I'll write it.

1. the original date format from comments.html : Feb.25,2015,11:31 a.m
2. ajax comments(temporary for new comments) : UTC 02:31:53 15-02-25

(both comments were written at 11:31, I wrote a comment and refresh, then add another comment right after.)

(if i refresh the page, the 2nd one disappear and all date format printed as 1st one.)

I don't know why the format i inputted does not work.

p.s)
...and one more, What should I do to print 'datetimefield' without time?
Need the DateTimeField for database but in a certain page i want to show just date, not time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a timezone-aware datetime as the `pub_date` when you create a new `ArticleComments` instance.

```
from django.utils import timezone

ac = ArticleComments.objects.create(
    ...
    pub_date = timezone.now().replace(microsecond=0),
    ...
)
```

Secondly, correct me if I am wrong but I think you should convert `ac. pub_date` to local time first prior to formatting it to a string:

```
 from django.utils import timezone

 data = {
     ...
     'pub_date': timezone.localtime(ac.pub_date).strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')),
     ...
 }
```

For your last question about converting a `datetime` object to `date` without time, you can call `.date()` method on that datetime.

```
>>> from django.utils.timezone import now

>>> today_as_date = now().date()
>>> today_as_date_str = today_as_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

For more information, you might want to take a look at the [timezone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/) in Django and [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: Thanks a lot. the timezone problem has solved!
few more questions: 
1. I wrote date first and then time in strftime, but why the time comes first?
2. 'datetime.date(2015, 2, 28) is not JSON serializable.' error occurred.. how could I pass the data by json?
3. If I pass FreeBoards object list to templates, how could I use strftime?
Please help me again.